# MQ locking slows down reader program

Tags: ibm-mq

If I keep 500 messages in a Websphere MQ queue and run by program that consumes the queue, it takes about 2-3 ms per message.

If I keep the consumer program running and keep putting messages on to the queue at the rate of 200 per sec, the reading program slows down drastically, taking about 200 ms per message.

I suspect some kind of locking that affects the consumer program. Are there any ways to work around this?

Thanks,

Yash

Comment: Can you say which API are using here? MQI C, JMS etc.  Also are these transactional, persistence messages?  How large the messages?

Comment: Also post your code for both put and get applications.

Comment: Also please post details in your question about whether putting application and getting application are running on the same machine or different machines, since if the same they will be affecting each other that way too.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure Morag will provide a much more technically detailed response, after you provide more information, but based solely on what you have presented -- The queue manager locks the queue access for single threaded access to the control blocks while a new message is being added, the overhead is in part dependent on the queue depth at the time.  A deeper queue may take longer to add a message to, especially if there is a non-blank correlid (insertion into sorted linked-list).